# Resolving 'UNEXPECTED STORE EXCEPTION' Blue Screen and Booting Issues on PC

Tags: windows, crash, bios

I'm experiencing a blue screen error on my PC with the "UNEXPECTED STORE EXCEPTION" stop code. After waiting for a while, it successfully restarts, but the problem persists. During startup, it gets stuck for an extended period, and instead of reaching the login screen, I encounter the message "reboot or select proper device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key," as shown in the video. According to my brother, it seems to be an issue with the OS. Are there any solutions to this problem?

[bluescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AjQt.jpg)

[video error at startup](https://pixeldrain.com/u/gGyyXunR)

i have tried to wait the bluescreen complete and restart my pc after that when startup instead of go to login screen it stuck at the start up and got the message "reboot or select proper device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key"

Comment: Likely a driver issue.  See if you can find a mini dump file and examine it with Nirsoft Blue Screen View

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand you to format your laptop and install windows again, because i have seen many people faces blue screen problem, and by formating it can be solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).